# Using WHERE and AND in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to run this query

```
select from_ from uploaded_emails1
where uploaded_emails1.from_ != 'test@email_domain.com'
and uploaded_emails1.from_ not in candidate_emails1.email
```

But I am getting the error `No such table candidate_emails1.email`. However if I run `select email from candidate_emails1` it runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alias candidate_emails1 is not defined in your sql

try

```
select from_ from uploaded_emails1
where uploaded_emails1.from_ != 'test@email_domain.com'
and uploaded_emails1.from_ not in(select emails from  candidate_emails1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT from_ FROM uploaded_emails1, candidate_emails1
WHERE uploaded_emails1.from_ != 'test@email_domain.com'
AND uploaded_emails1.from_ != candidate_emails1.email
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this, by either using a `NOT IN` clause or a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
    from_
FROM uploaded_emails1
WHERE uploaded_emails1.from_ != 'test@email_domain.com'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM candidate_emails1
    WHERE candidate_emails1.email = uploaded_emails1.from_
);
```

...or...

```
SELECT
    from_
FROM uploaded_emails1
WHERE uploaded_emails1.from_ != 'test@email_domain.com'
AND uploaded_emails1.from_ NOT IN (
    SELECT email
    FROM candidate_emails1
);
```